# How does the preprocessor work in C?

Tags: c

Why is the answer for the below code 16? Can anybody explain the working of this program?

```
#define SQUARE(n) n*n
void main()
{
    int j;      
    j =16/SQUARE(2);

    printf("\n j=%d",j);
    getch();
}
```

If we write the same code like below, then the answer is 4:

```
//the ans is 4 why?
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define SQUARE(n) n*n

void main()
{
    int j;      
    j =16/(SQUARE(2));

    printf("\n j=%d",j);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: This is one of many reasons why you should avoid function-like macros.

Comment: To parenthesis or not to parenthesis. That is the question. And the answer is use parenthesis whenever you write expressions.

Comment: Yes, many unexpected things will happen for beginners espicially.

Comment: Note that if you had written `j = 16 / SQUARE(1 + 1);`, your answer would be 18, but if you had written `j = 16 / (SQUARE(1 + 1));`, your answer would have been 5.  Also, the return type of `main()` should be `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll get

```
j =16/2*2; // (16 / 2) * 2 = 16
```

Comment: I think 16/2*2 is same as (16/2)*2 so it is 16. Thank you Johann

Comment: *\*duh\** Math is hard... Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

The preprocessor just replaces the text, exactly as written.

So, the macro call `SQUARE(2)` becomes literally `2*2`.

In your case, that means the whole expression becomes `16/2*2`, which because of [C's precedence rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence) evaluates to (16/2)*2, i.e. 16.

Macros should always be enclosed in parenthesis, and have each argument enclosed as well.

If we do that, we get:

```
#define SQUARE(n)  ((n) * (n))
```

which replaces to `16/((2) * (2))`, which evaluates as 16/4, i.e. 4.

The parens around each argument makes things like `SQUARE(1+1)` work as expected, without them a call such as `16/SQUARE(1+1)` would become `16/(1+1*1+1)` which is `16/3`, i.e. not at all what you'd want.

Comment: Superb explaination. Thank you so much unwind.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your macro with insulating parentheses, like so:

```
 #define SQUARE(n) ((n)*(n))
```

Otherwise

```
 j = 16/SQUARE(2);
```

expands to

```
j = 16 / 2 * 2;   which is equivalent to (16 / 2) * 2
```

When what you want is

```
j = 16 / (2 * 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Order of operations. Your expression is evaluating to:

```
 j = 16 / 2 * 2
```

which equals 16. Make it:

```
#define SQUARE(n) (n*n)
```

which will force the square to be evaluated first.

Comment: Now, i know the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. When using macros that are to be used as expressions, you should parenthesise the whole macro body.

This prevents erroneous expansions like:

```
#define SQUARE(x) x*x
-SQUARE(5,5)
// becomes -5 * 5
```

#### 2. If the macro arguments are expreessions, you should parenthesise them too.

This prevents a different type of problems:

```
#define SQUARE(x) x*x
SQUARE(5+2)
// becomes 5 + 2*5 + 2
```

---

Hence the correct way is to write it like this:

```
#define square(n) ((n)*(n))
-SQUARE(5+2)
// becomes -((5+2)*(5+2))
```

Using macros as functions is discouraged though (guess why), so use a function instead. For instance:

```
inline double square(n) { return n*n; }
```

Comment: Thank you Kos. Thanks for you explaination.

Answer (score 2):

The Expansion of macro will be like:

```
  j = 16/SQUARE(2);
  j = 16/2*2;
```

Which is equal to : `j = (16/2)*2;` Means `j = 16;`

and :

```
 j = 16/(SQUARE(2));
 j = 16/(2*2);
```

Which is equal to : `j = 16/4;` Means `j = 4;`

Comment: Thank you Midhun, I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

Because the macro will be expanded as:

```
j = 16/2*2;
```

The pre-compiler does not do any processing on the expansion. It places the expanded macro in your code as it is. Since you have not parenthesized the replacement text it wont do it for you in the main code as well. Make it :

```
#define SQUARE(n) ((n)*(n))
```

Comment: Thank you Deepankar, Now I know it.

Comment: Although your alternative definition is better, it runs into problems with SQUARE(1+1), which gives 3 with your code. Parenthesize each argument, and the expression as a whole: `#define SQUARE(n) ((n) * (n))`.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is evaluated as:

```
16 / 2 * 2
(16 / 2) * 2
8 * 2
16
```

The second example is evaluated as:

```
16 / (2 * 2)
16 / 4
4
```

Add parenthesis to you preprocessor statement to control the order of operations:

```
#define SQUARE(n) ((n)*(n))
```

The outer parenthesis in ((n)*(n)) ensure that n is squared before any outside operation is performed. The inner parenthesis (n) ensure that n is correctly evaluated in cases where you pass an expression to SQUARE like so:

```
16 / SQUARE(2 * 2)
16 / ((2 * 2)*(2 * 2))
16 / (4 * 4)
16 / 16
1
```

Comment: Yes Nocturno, now I understand. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
Its because Whenever macro name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro.its simple rule of working of macro.


Case 1 : result 16

        define SQUARE(n) n*n
        void main()
         {
            int j;      
            j =16/SQUARE(2);

          printf("\n j=%d",j);
          getch();
       }

its get expand as below


j =16/SQUARE(2); 

so in place of SQUARE(2) it will replace 2*2 because Macro is SQUARE(n) n*n

j = 16/2*2
j = (16/2)*2
j = 8*2
j =16



Case 2 : result 4



        define SQUARE(n) n*n

        void main()
       {
            int j;      
            j =16/(SQUARE(2));

          printf("\n j=%d",j);
          getch();
       }



its get expand as below


j =16/(SQUARE(2));

so in place of SQUARE(2) it will replace 2*2 because Macro is SQUARE(n) n*n

j = 16/(2*2)
j = 16/(4)
j = 4


Hope this will help
```